# I want to display two images at the same ViewController using 2 buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display two images at the same ViewController using 2 buttons. How do I do that?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GetImagesViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func selectSignature1(_ sender: Any) {
        openPhotoLibraryForSelectSignature()
    }

    @IBAction func selectPhoto(_sender: Any){
        openPhotoLibraryForSelectPhoto()
    }

    func openPhotoLibraryForSelectSignature() {
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) else {
            print("can't open photo library")
            return
        }

        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }

    func openPhotoLibraryForSelectPhoto() {
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) else {
            print("can't open photo library")
            return
        }

        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        imageView1.image = image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable called `focus` that points to the `UIImageView` you're about to change. When the user has picked an image, just update the image of the `focus`.

```
class GetImagesViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var focus: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func selectSignature1(_ sender: Any) {
        focus = imageView1
        openPhotoLibraryForSelectSignature()

    }
    @IBAction func selectPhoto(_sender: Any){
        focus = imageView2
        openPhotoLibraryForSelectPhoto()
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        focus.image = image
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I am very happy to hear that!

Comment: @ocsahan you still have redundant code. You have two different methods for presenting UIImagePickerController

Comment: @RobertDresler hi, can you please tell what are those methods?

Comment: @RanjithiOS `openPhotoLibraryForSelectSignature()` and `openPhotoLibraryForSelectPhoto()`. The both do the same thing, so you can have one method for it: for example `openPhotoLibrary()`

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the explanation and your time